# How to set default editor/viewer for Midnight Commander to Sublime

Tags: mc

The question is quite straightforward, so no further description is needed according to me.

I just add that I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Midnight Commander go to Options menu / Configuration... command / Use internal edit checkbox and uncheck it. (Don't forget to execute the Save setup command if the Auto save setup option is off.)

Then set the `EDITOR` environment variable to Sublime. You may prefer to add one of these to your shell's resource file:

- Global setting for all programs that use `EDITOR` (not recommended):

  ```
  EDITOR=sublime
  export EDITOR
  ```
- Temporary setting for the given Midnight Commander session only:

  ```
  alias mc='EDITOR=sublime mc'
  ```

Same for the viewer, just you uncheck the Use internal view option and set the `VIEWER` environment variable instead.

Comment: why is it not recommended to set `EDITOR=sublime` globally?

Comment: Because other tools, for example `crontab`, are using it. Such tools may be used without X (for example from a virtual terminal in single user mode for maintenance operations) or by user who has no running X instance (for example through `su -`). So better keep `EDITOR` set to a text mode editor.

Comment: Why 'EDITOR='sublime -w' does not work? (It seems MC ignore any supplyed options)

Answer (score 35):

Run MC as usual. On the command line right above the bottom row of menu selections type

```
select-editor
```

This should open a menu with a list of all of your installed editors. This is working for me on all my current Linux machines.

Comment: Doesn't work on OSX though.

Comment: Perfect on Debian!

Comment: doesn't show a list to select, just command not found!

Comment: @datdinhquoc you need to install [`sensible-utils` package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/sensible-utils)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score -1):

Although this topic is old, Midnight Commander keeps using `vi` as default in my Tumbleweed.

I checked the setup on my Raspberry (that is Debian based Buster). At first run mc offers there "select editor", that is creating a writable file in `$HOME/.selected_editor`.  You can create it with

```
touch $HOME/.selected_editor
```

It further has a symlink

```
/etc/alternatives/@editor pointing to /usr/bin/nano
```

Create that symlink and save the three further **executable** script files in `/usr/bin`:

**sensible-pager**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Prevent recursive loops, where these values are set to this script
p="$(which sensible-pager)"
[ "$(which $PAGER || true)" = "$p" ] && PAGER=

${PAGER:-pager} "$@"
ret="$?"
if [ "$ret" -eq 126 ] || [ "$ret" -eq 127 ]; then
    more "$@"
    ret="$?"
    if [ "$ret" -eq 126 ] || [ "$ret" -eq 127 ]; then
        echo "Couldn't find a pager!" 1>&2
        echo "Set the \$PAGER environment variable to your desired pager." 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

**sensible-editor**

```
#!/bin/sh

ret="$?"

# Prevent recursive loops, where these values are set to this script
p="$(which sensible-editor)"
[ "$(which $EDITOR || true)" = "$p" ] && EDITOR=
[ "$(which $VISUAL || true)" = "$p" ] && VISUAL=
[ "$(which $SELECTED_EDITOR || true)" = "$p" ] && SELECTED_EDITOR=

if [ -n "$VISUAL" ]; then
    ${VISUAL} "$@"
    ret="$?"
    if [ "$ret" -ne 126 ] && [ "$ret" -ne 127 ]; then
        exit "$ret"
    fi
fi

if [ -r ~/.selected_editor ]; then
    . ~/.selected_editor 2>/dev/null || true
elif [ -z "$EDITOR" ] && [ -z "$SELECTED_EDITOR" ] && [ -t 0 ]; then
    select-editor && . ~/.selected_editor 2>/dev/null || true
fi
${EDITOR:-${SELECTED_EDITOR:-editor}} "$@"
ret="$?"
if [ "$ret" -eq 126 ] || [ "$ret" -eq 127 ]; then
    nano "$@"
    ret="$?"
    if [ "$ret" -eq 126 ] || [ "$ret" -eq 127 ]; then
        nano-tiny "$@"
        ret="$?"
        if [ "$ret" -eq 126 ] || [ "$ret" -eq 127 ]; then
            vi "$@"
            ret="$?"
            if [ "$ret" -eq 126 ] || [ "$ret" -eq 127 ]; then
                echo "Couldn't find an editor!" 1>&2
                echo "Set the \$EDITOR environment variable to your desired editor." 1>&2
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi
exit "$ret"
```

**sensible-browser**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Prevent recursive loops, where these values are set to this script
p="$(which sensible-browser)"
[ "$(which $BROWSER || true)" = "$p" ] && BROWSER=

if test -n "$BROWSER"; then
    ${BROWSER} "$@"
    ret="$?"
    if [ "$ret" -ne 126 ] && [ "$ret" -ne 127 ]; then
        exit "$ret"
    fi
fi

if test -n "$DISPLAY"; then
    if test -n "$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID"; then
        if test -x /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser; then
            exec /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser "$@"
        elif test -x /usr/bin/x-www-browser; then
            exec /usr/bin/x-www-browser "$@"
        elif test -x /usr/bin/gnome-terminal && test -x /usr/bin/www-browser; then
            exec /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x /usr/bin/www-browser "$@"
        fi
    fi
    if test -x /usr/bin/x-www-browser; then
        exec /usr/bin/x-www-browser "$@"
    elif test -x /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator && test -x /usr/bin/www-browser; then
        exec /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -x /usr/bin/www-browser "$@"
    fi
elif test -x /usr/bin/www-browser; then
    exec /usr/bin/www-browser "$@"
fi

printf "Couldn't find a suitable web browser!\n" >&2
printf "Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.\n" >&2 
exit 1;
```

I was really surprised but after these steps nano is the editor when using <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: "[...] _save the three further executable script files in `/usr/bin`_" **OR** install [sensible-utils](https://packages.debian.org/buster/sensible-utils).