# midnight commander: settings for mcview not honored

Tags: colors, mc

`Midnight Commander`  supports skins, where custom colors can be defined. I have created my own skin with custom colors. However, I am unable to change the color for the internal viewer (`mcview`). Whatever I define, my colors are being ignored and default colors are used instead.

snippet from my skin `.ini` file is below:

```
[core]
    _default_=lightgray;blue
    selected=black;cyan
    marked=yellow;blue
    .....

.....

[viewer]
    _default_=lightgray;black
    viewbold=yellow;blue
    viewunderline=brightred;blue
    viewselected=yellow;cyan

.....
```

The `_default_` parameter in the `[viewer]` section is completely ignored. Whatever I put there, the displayed colors will be the ones defined in the '[core]' section (lightgray;blue). In other words, I am unable to override the default colors in `mcview`.

Can somebody please advise, how I can define different colors for the internal viewer?

Comment: Presuming everyone defines `_default_` first, `grep -C 3 _default_ /usr/share/mc/skins/*.ini | egrep -A 2 "viewer|core"` implies none of the stock skins try to set `viewer` differently than `core` here -- you could file it as a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mcview has ugly blue/grey colors. It is possible to have better view with '-b' option. I added to my ~/.bash_aliases

```
alias mc='mc -b'
```

and this makes mcview to show text in black and white mode.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/440755)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mcview does not react on color settings (it is a bug). Use another viewer, disable internal viewer in the Menu: Options (F9) -> Configuration -> uncheck Use internal view
or type  ~/.config/mc/ini and find line 'use_internal_view=' and type 'false' there.

Your external viewer it is "VIEWER" environment variable which you can set up in .bashrc like 'VIEWER=vim' or run mc like this: 'VIEWER=vim' mc

[How to set default editor/viewer for Midnight Commander to Sublime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80845/how-to-set-default-editor-viewer-for-midnight-commander-to-sublime/80852#80852)

Comment: also you can run mc in black and white mode: mc -b